# Bluetooth, sound not working with Ubuntu 22.04 on macbook pro

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, macbook-pro, speakers

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on macbook pro 2017 but the sound and bluetooth not are working.

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade`, it may be due to bad drivers, if that doesn't work, try [updating the kernal.](https://learnubuntu.com/upgrade-kernel/)